# php imagegif() direct output fails but indirect output works

Tags: php, image

I have a php script that is supposed to create and display an image.

The image is displayed properly on the webpage when using this code:

```
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
readfile('picture.gif');
//rest of code creating the image
imagegif($im,'picture.gif');
```

But, the image is not displayed when using this code:

```
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
//rest of code creating the image
imagegif($im);
```

In the php documentation for imagegif, this code is given as an example:

```
<?php
// Create a new image instance
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);

// Make the background white
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 99, 99, 0xFFFFFF);

// Draw a text string on the image
imagestring($im, 3, 40, 20, 'GD Library', 0xFFBA00);

// Output the image to browser
header('Content-Type: image/gif');

imagegif($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you setting the `$im` variable before calling it? If not, the first code is working because of `readfile` function, not because your `imagegif`.

Comment: Yes. How else would the correct image be getting saved each time as `picture.gif` in the first place?

Comment: Can you show us the entire code?

Comment: Where is your `$im = imagecreatefromgif('picture.gif');` or are you not using a beginning `gif`?